# How to create an array of objects with strings and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have to create an array in the following format

```
var myData = [
  {
    x: "10:00",
    y: [15, 30],
  },
];
```

Where my code looks like

```
myData.push({
  x: startingHoursToPush + ":00",
  y: "[" + startingHours[1] + "," + endingHours[1] + "]",
});
```

but the result I get is as following

```
x: "11:00"
y: "[15,30]"
```

I need to make the values for y an array instead of a string

Comment: `"["` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Yes, I am struggling to make the values of y as an array

Comment: Just use `[` and `]` without quotes to declare an array-literal.

Answer (score 1):

use either `[ ]`

```
myData.push({
  x: startingHoursToPush + ":00",
  y: [startingHours[1],endingHours[1]],
});
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/urLgqpcm/)

OR

use array inside

```
myData.push({
      x: startingHoursToPush + ":00",
      y: new Array(startingHours[1],endingHours[1]),
    });
```

[**DEMO FIDDLE 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/urLgqpcm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You are making a string instead of an array, try this instead

```js
myData.push({
  x: startingHoursToPush + ":00",
  y: [startingHours[1], endingHours[1]],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

JS is wonderful. Just wrap it in `[]` brackets.

```
myData.push({
  x: startingHoursToPush + ":00",
  y: [startingHours[1] , endingHours[1] ],
});
```